Matching power supply to a four pin connector
There is a Power supply called HRPG-150-48. I need to deliver its voltage into a special 4 pin kind of connector.
For me a connector needs only two pins GND and voltage.
Given the data sheet of the power supply where could you recommend me to connect connector to this power supply?
Thanks.

It's impossible for us to know how you need to connect a power supply to a connector when you're not telling us anything about the device that connector connects to. You just need to match what that device expects.

Please add what is the question about? You have the pinout of the supply, and you likely know what pinout you need for the custom connector, so what do you mean by "where", location perhaps?

What are you going to use as the load? What's the current draw?

The current is 4A ,I just need to know according to the datasheet where are the wires of the DC output and how do i connect them to the connector.

@scot123 The current is 4A yet you have a supply rated at 3.3A.

...and you're using a connector rated at 3A maximum,

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You’ve got a supply with positive and negative and remote voltage sense capability. The connector has four pins, so you could either connect two pins to positive and two to negative to double the current handling, or you could use two pins for the voltage and two for the remote sensing.
The connector doesn’t show a current rating, so you’ll also have to make sure it can handle the current your device draws.
